# Unable to pass/receive prop value in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating my first vuejs component with looks like this:

```
// modal.vue
<template>
 <div id='my-modal'>

    <div class='modal'>
        {{ title }}
    </div>

 </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    template: '#my-modal',
    props: ['title'],

    created () {
        console.log('modal works')
    }
}

</script>
```

The goal is to import that file and call if via `<modal></modal>` tag and pass title to it. This is the file where I am importing the above modal.

```
// home.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <modal :title='title'></modal>
    </div>
</template>
<script> 
import modal from './modal'
export default {

    components: {modal},
    data () {
        return {
            title: "HELLO!!"
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

However, despite passing `<modal :title='title'></modal>` I can't display the title in the first example.

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are specifying a `template` property for the `modal.vue` component. don't do that, the `<template>` section gets used as the template automatically.

Comment: @thanksd hmm? I know the root elements should be left alone, so I am not touching `<template></template>` if you mean the child to this tag should not have a prop, then I tried that as well `<template><div> .... </div></template>` and still the same thing.

Comment: No, I mean `template: '#my-modal',`. Just remove that line

Comment: @thanksd Did that, still can't see the `{{title}}` btw: I am trying to make this a component, like `vue.component('modal', {})'` so if I remove that line, it means I can't reference the js code / props to the template

Comment: That's not true, the `.vue` file will generate a Vue instance using the `<template>` section. You do not need to specify a `template` property in the `<script>` section. Also, you should show all relevant code. The code you've shared will work if you remove the `template: '#my-modal'` line. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think that's only if you you have the main `Vue = new Vue()` instance and and you inject the component as `Vue.component()` anyway, I couldn't get this page to run, but this https://codesandbox.io/s/9j4909jkvp is pretty much what I have on local as well. Can you check and let me know if something is not right

Comment: As the error is pointing out, you need a comma after `components: {modal}` in your `Hello.vue` file but otherwise it runs fine.

Comment: did u import bootstrap or any other css framework?

Comment: @thanksd thanks it worked. It's too bad though that I didn't want to make a component without providing `template: '#some-id'` or `vue.component('foobar', {template: `<p>...</p>`})` because I think that is the recommended way. Right now I am just exporting a file that contains vue template and a separate js code... somehow it seem like hack to me... but you saved me the headache

Answer (score 1):

Can't see anything wrong with the code. so my **guess** is as follows:

you have imported bootstrap.
bootstrap contains a file called: `modals.less`

it contains css code that puts your component on `display:none`.
try to change the class name of the root div of `modal.vue`  to something else like: `hidar` and report back.

```
// Modals
// --------------------------------------------------

// .modal-open      - body class for killing the scroll
// .modal           - container to scroll within
// .modal-dialog    - positioning shell for the actual modal
// .modal-content   - actual modal w/ bg and corners and shit

// Kill the scroll on the body
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

// Container that the modal scrolls within
.modal {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: @zindex-modal;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

## EDIT 1

Any other css frameworks or files you have on your project could cause such problems (personally i could reproduce it with bootstrap).
the key debugging step you have to do is as follows:

1. Open Chrome Dev tools. find `<div class="modal">`
2. See if it contains the text. it probably contains the text. i don't
   see any reason it wouldn't
3. Inspect the styling. look for `display:none` , or any other css styling that can interfere with displaying text.